# Running Server Edge SDK with OSGI Framework in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I followed the instructions [here](http://wiki.rifidi.net/index.php?title=Edge_Server_Development_Environment) about setting up a development environment in order to either develop a custom Rifidi Edge Server(RFID Middleware) application, or modify an existing Edge Server bundle.
every thing was ok but when i clicked on run button,instead of 'OSGi:'
i saw this Error:

Error: Could not find or load main class Document\eclipse

It may be necessary to say i use 64 bit version of eclipse:

Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers

Version: Juno Service Release 1

What does this error mean?

Is it a common error in OSGi frameworks ?

Does OSGi has main class Or Method Or something like it!

What should i do to run it correctly ?

Maybe my Questions make it clear that i am new in OSGi so 
I will be grateful if someone Help me.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it !

that was because of this VM argument:
-Dorg.rifidi.home=${workspace_loc}/Rifidi-SDK/RifidiHome

When i removed it from run configuration i could run it without any problem. 
just it!